# How can get JPA to use an outer-join on a condition involving an associated entity?

Tags: java, jpql

I have two JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class TaskSchedule {
    ...
    private String name;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Task {
    ...
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    private TaskSchedule taskSchedule;
    ...
}
```

I would like to have a query that looks like this:

```
select t
from Task t
where t.description like '%text%' or t.taskSchedule.name like '%text%'
```

Not all Tasks have a TaskSchedule. The above JPQL query generates an inner-join in the resulting SQL, which excludes all of the tasks without a TaskSchedule.

How can I tell JPA to perform an outer-join in the generated SQL?

I am using Hibernate EntityManager as the JPA implementation.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an outer join in JPQL like you do in SQL, through the `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` keywords. The [JPQL Language Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_outer_joins) has a pretty good example of this.

Freehanding this, the finished JPQL will probably look similar to:

```
select t
from Task t left outer join t.taskSchedule ts
where t.description like '%text%' or ts.name like '%text%'
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I have read the docs, but must have missed this bit - doh!